# How to make passwordless switch to another user in a shell script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sudo, sudoers

I want to su from hadoopmaster to hduser. When I do it on the terminal, I do:

```
su - hduser
```

which then asks me for the password and I enter it and I get in to hduser. How can I do the same in a shell script without having to worry about the password? I tried the `sudoers` file method where I put:

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
hduser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
hadoopmaster ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/su hduser 
(here I tried different combinations of the line with and without the '-' and also 
with and without /bin)
```

I did this and when I do `su hduser` or `su - hduser`, it prompts me for the password again. What do I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't use "su" with the sudoers file, you need to use "sudo". So, you'd want a command line like:

`sudo su - hduser`

which would do want you want, provided you had the appropriate lines in the sudoers file. A line like this:

`hadoopmaster ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: su - hduser`

should do the trick.

Comment: Cool. I'll try it out. Thanks! :) I'll let you know by tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: I've found a bit easier way to do this. In `sudoers` use the line `hadoopmaster ALL=(hduser) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh`. Then you can simply type `sudo -s -u hduser` to switch to the new user.

Answer (score 0):

I have add user= ranjith on /etc/sudoers file like,

```
 ranjith ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now we can use,

```
 "sudo, sudoedit - execute a command as another user"

 [ranjith@ranjith ~]$ sudo -i
 # id
 uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Its working for me and Now i can login to root from my local user "ranjith" directly.

Comment: This is a very bad idea unless you intent to create another root user. You're effectively granting the user "ranjith" unrestricted super user permissions, which is not the intention of this question. Please use this sudoer rule with caution.